# Calling another Method from object-Java

Tags: java, composition

I'm stumped.  I created a method called "makeBed" in the (BedRoom) class that calls another method in the (Bed) class called "make". But when I try to call the method via bedroom.makeBed(); it does not work. I put a // in the part i'm trying to get to work.

Main

```
public class Main {
Wall wall1 = new Wall("West");
Wall wall2 = new Wall("East");
Wall wall3 = new Wall("South");
Wall wall4 = new Wall("North");

Ceiling ceiling = new Ceiling(12, 55);

Bed bed = new Bed("Modern", 4, 3, 2, 1);

Lamp lamp = new Lamp("classic", false, 75);

BedRoom bedroom = new BedRoom("test",wall1,wall2,wall3,wall4,ceiling,bed,lamp);

bedroom.makeBed(); //bedroom.makeBed(); does not work 
//It does not show the public method "makeBed" in the BedRoom class
}
```

BedRoom Class

```
public class BedRoom {
private String name;
private Wall wall1;
private Wall wall2;
private Wall wall3;
private Wall wall4;
private Ceiling ceiling;
private Bed bed;
private Lamp lamp;

public BedRoom(String name, Wall wall1, Wall wall2, Wall wall3, Wall wall4, Ceiling ceiling, Bed bed, Lamp lamp) {
   this.name = name;
    this.wall1 = wall1;
    this.wall2 = wall2;
    this.wall3 = wall3;
    this.wall4 = wall4;
    this.ceiling = ceiling;
    this.bed = bed;
    this.lamp = lamp;
}

public Lamp getLamp(){
    return this.lamp;
}

public void makeBed(){              //This is the method I'm trying to access
    System.out.println("Bedroom -> Making bed");
    bed.make();
}

}
```

Bed Class

```
public class Bed {
private String style;
private int pillows;
private int height;
private int sheets;
private int quilt;

public Bed(String style, int pillows, int height, int sheets, int quilt) {
    this.style = style;
    this.pillows = pillows;
    this.height = height;
    this.sheets = sheets;
    this.quilt = quilt;
}

public void make(){ 
    System.out.println("Bed -< Making"); //Method I'm trying to call
}

public String getStyle() {
    return style;
}

public int getPillows() {
    return pillows;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public int getSheets() {
    return sheets;
}

public int getQuilt() {
    return quilt;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't see it?  Your code looks fine and should compile and run.

Comment: @RobertMoskal When I type in bedroom.  the methods do not show

Comment: That's an editor specific issue, having to do with code completion.  You have to tell us what editor you are using and how it is set up.

Comment: @Robertmoskal Actually the problem was I forgot to put the Public Static Void Main. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to say this is it... You don't have your code wrapped into a method so it not compiling right.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Wall wall1 = new Wall("West");
Wall wall2 = new Wall("East");
Wall wall3 = new Wall("South");
Wall wall4 = new Wall("North");

Ceiling ceiling = new Ceiling(12, 55);

Bed bed = new Bed("Modern", 4, 3, 2, 1);

Lamp lamp = new Lamp("classic", false, 75);

BedRoom bedroom = new BedRoom("test",wall1,wall2,wall3,wall4,ceiling,bed,lamp);

bedroom.makeBed(); //bedroom.makeBed(); does not work 
//It does not show the public method "makeBed" in the BedRoom class
}
}
```

Maybe that will work.

**This is on the assumption that THIS is your class you want to initilize the whole script from, if not change `public static void main(String[] args){}` into `public Main() {}`**

Comment: Wow... I forgot to put public static void main... I have been looking all over for what I did wrong... Sometimes the answer is right in front of you.  Thank you Matt

Comment: Haha, it's fine. We all make our newbie mistakes. Get some java and keep going! ;) Don't forget to make this as the right answer!